# Why do I get this error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Video without an ID):
  app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:52:in `topic_update'
```

It's referring to this action in my videos controller:

```
def topic_update
  @video = Video.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @video.update_attributes(params[:video])
      format.html { redirect_to(@video) }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    end
 end
end
```

The error is thrown after this form sends a PUT request:

```
<%= form_for @video, :url => {:action => "topic_update"}, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.text_field :topic_names, :class => "topic_field" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Add Topic", :id => 'topic_submit' %>
<% end %>
```

This is what happens according to my logs:

```
Started PUT "/topic/update.js" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Apr 11 00:12:19 -0700 2011
  Processing by VideosController#topic_update as JS
  Parameters: {"video"=>{"topic_names"=>"eedefva"}}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 57 LIMIT 1
```

I have this in my routes.rb file:

```
resources :videos
match '/topic/update' => "videos#topic_update"
```

Comment: how can I fix that? If I change the form to `:url => {:action => "update"}` then it works all of a sudden... but I want to go to the topic_update method

Comment: You are not passing `id` parameter in request. Check your route.config file. Check url to see whether you are passing id as a parameter or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your 'topic_update' method will treat as a 'GET' method where as you want it as a post method,

try this in your routes.rb

```
resources :videos do
  member do
    put 'topic_update'
  end
end
```

I haven't tested this but :D

read here for more info (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

HTH

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are trying to update a non-existent (not saved before) object.
This method `form_for @video` would add `id` parameter if `@video` is referring to an existent record that was saved before.

Please make sure you're calling update procedure (showing "edit" form) only if `@video` corresponds to a stored record.